# API key for GCM

Tags: android, api, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When using the API key generated for my project from Google developer console in the server side to send GCM - Push notifications, i am getting a 'MismatchSenderId' error. I have cross checked the sender ID in my application and the API key also, which is correct.

Also when creating an API key for push notification implementation, should i go for 'Server key' or 'Browser key' or 'Android key' .I have maps implementation also in my project.
I am new to push notification implementation, so kindly excuse if question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

when creating an API key for push notification implementation, use:

- **Server Key** to send from your server
- **Browser Key** to send from a web app
- **Android Key** to send from an android app.

also the **Sender Id**, is really the **project id**.